Accelerometer and Gyroscope filtering
I have configured my accelerometer and gyroscope ODR for 200Hz and reading data from sensor every 100Hz/10msec from mcu.
I will be implementing LPF and HPF for above sensor data.
What will be the sampling frequency for this filter? Is it 100 or 200?
